# In Oracle Apex 5, how can I to create a custom login page with authentication?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How would I create a username and login page and authentication in Oracle Apex 5? Also, the password field turning input into "****" stars instead of revealing their password.

I'm a beginner in PL-SQL.

Comment: Newly created APEX application has login page and authentication by default. Just click "Create application". See also: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle-apex/2759/getting-started-with-oracle-apex/25374/hello-world-application#t=20161121212937568761

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I create a username and login page and authentication in apex 5 ? Also, the password field turning input into "****" stars instead of revealing their password.

Simply change "Page Item Input Type" to Password instead of Text Field.